# Convert an avro file that was originally a json back to json with Python

Tags: python, json, type-conversion, avro, azure-eventhub

So I'm trying to read a JSON file that I send via HTTP POST to an Event Hub that captures the data and converts it to an Avro file format in an Azure Blob Storage, now I'd like to download that file again and convert it back to a JSON format using Python.
Is using a JSON serializer the only way to do this?

Initial JSON format

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "number": "111111111",
  "payload": {
    "intial": "This is a example",
    "BoxId": 2,
    "PersonId": 2,
    "GUID": "1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e",
    "borderId": 2,
    "ServiceId": 2,
    "Lat": -63.546547,
    "Lon": -63.546547,
    "TimeStamp": "2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z",
    "Recording": "azezaerazre",
    "Env": "TEST"
  },
  "operator": 123456,
  "sender": "MSD",
  "binary": 1,
  "sent": "2021-03-29T08:29:36.758Z"
}
```

Comment: When you ask "Is using a JSON serializer the only way to do this?", it sounds like you are looking for another option. But if you want the end result to be in a JSON format, isn't a JSON serializer exactly what you are looking for? If you wanted it in XML you'd probably use a utility that would serialize the data to XML, right?

Comment: @Scott I would like to know if there is another way because I can't manage to do it with a serializer. I am quite new to programming. I have looked at 'AvroJsonSerializer' but there is not enough documentation to help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have downloaded the Avro file, you should be able to output the records as Avro JSON by using `fastavro` and doing something like this:

```py
from fastavro import reader, json_writer

with open("json_file.json", "w") as json_file:
    with open("avro_file.avro", "rb") as avro_file:
        avro_reader = reader(avro_file)
        json_writer(json_file, avro_reader.writer_schema, avro_reader)
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott! The difficulty is that I send my initial JSON data via Postman to blob storage, so "normally" I don't have access to my initial JSON data. How should I proceed if I only have access to my Avro file and that I would like to read it in a JSON format again?

Comment: I believe the code I posted should work for your case. "json_file.json" is just a placeholder for whatever you want to call your JSON file. "avro_file.avro" is a placeholder for the name of the avro file that you have downloaded.

Comment: Okay, I understood it, I just tried it out and I can confirm that it works, thanks, Scott!